# Function call as an another function argument (refactor)

Tags: refactoring

I was looking for existing questions that could help me but I couldn't really find one - maybe I had trouble with "building" the question properly, So  I'm sorry if this does exist already.

Let's get to the point: I have a function that takes one argument of `List<string>` type and returns let's say a formatted list:

```
private List<string> BasicMethod(List<string> addresses)
```

so normally, you would call

```
var someAddresses = AnotherMethod();
var formattedAddresses = BasicMethod(someAddresses);
```

But I wanted to refactor the code so I skipped the `someAddresses` variable and I called the function like that:

```
var formattedAddresses = BasicMethod(AnotherMethod());
```

**Question:** Is it considered a good thing to pass a function argument as an another function call or does this affect *readability* and the overall "*cleanliness*" of the code in the negative way?

Thanks for all of the answers and as always, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use variable `someAddresses` only in this scope of code, then you can use a direct call of function instead variable. But you should name your function `AnotherMethod` in a good style for clearness.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. And yes, the methods name should have a good and descriptive names. Methods from my example are not named properly because it wasn't the point of my question, but thank you anyway :)